# OpenERP customized module with button object

Tags: function, odoo

I have created a customized module i openerp with following .py file . Please help me to add first and second to get third using button object click function.

```
from osv import osv

from osv import fields

class test_base(osv.osv):
    _name='test.base'
    _columns={


            'first':fields.integer('First No:'),
            'second':fields.integer('Second No:'),
            'third':fields.integer('Third No:'),    
             }

def get_sum(self, cr, uid, ids,context=None):

     #  please add code here to get sum of 'first' and 'second' and assign to variable 'sum'

    return {'value':{'third': sum }}



test_base()
```

xml

```
<button name="get_sum" string="Click on me to get sum " type="object"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code you can do onething

```
 def get_sum(self, cr, uid, ids,context=None):

    #  please add code here to get sum of 'first' and 'second' and assign to variable 'sum'
    sum = 0.0
    for data in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
       sum += data.first + data.second
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'third': sum}
    return True
```

or you can make third fields as functional field and get value directly there without click on button

_columns = {
    'first':fields.integer('First No:'),
    'second':fields.integer('Second No:'),
    'third': fields.function(_sum, type="float", store=True)
}

```
def get_sum(self, cr, uid, ids,context=None):
        res = {}
        #  please add code here to get sum of 'first' and 'second' and assign to variable 'sum'
        sum = 0.0
        for data in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
           sum += data.first + data.second
        res[data.id] = sum
        return res
```

you can not use this type return  **return {'value':{'third': sum }}** in button clicl event it only work in onchange method, like you set onchange on fiels second so when you enter value and press tab it onchange fire set value in field third.

hope this help

Comment: Thank you very much for complete information. I wanted to use button click event explicitly. Thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: Added parenthesis at the end and executed .  it is working fine .                                     self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'third': sum})

Comment: one quick sub question on this....  Can we disable this button when record is not in editable mode. Right now this button is enabledeven when record is not in editable mode

Comment: <button name="button_reset_taxes" states="draft,proforma2"
                                        string="(update)" class="oe_link oe_edit_only"
                                        type="object" help="Recompute taxes and total"/> you can use **class** here it will do when editable

Comment: Thanks Again!. I have added class="oe_link oe_edit_only" and it is working fine. However i have come across another issue where in button changed to link (Previosly button was dispayed now same button is not getting displayed, instead link is displayed.   <button name="my_button_display" string="Display"  class="oe_link oe_edit_only" type="object" />

Comment: hi then remove the "oe_lin" from class="oe_link oe_edit_only" and write like <button name="my_button_display" string="Display" class="oe_edit_only" type="object" />